# Always get an error with combining if and logical & statement in R

Tags: r

I am always getting an error when I try to combine if statement with logical & statement in R.

I have 2 data, `f` is a data frame and `st_dev` is a numeric class.

I try to run this:

```
for (w in 1:100){
if (((f[[w]]>0.02) & ((st_dev[w]-st_dev[w+1])>abs(0.0025)))==1){
o[w]<-index(f[w])
break}}}
```

But then I get the error message:

> Error in if statement, missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: ...and three right curly brackets but only two left ones.

Comment: Only the first element in a vector given to if() will be evaluated and used. Please post code with test cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because you have missing values in your `f` data. Try catching NAs using `is.na()` or filter out NAs before you iterate though your data.

You may not want to completely omit values with NA, but one way to test if this is really your issue is to run `f <- na.omit(f)` then try your loop. If it then runs, you'll know that NAs in f were your issue.